# Most elegant way to change 0 to 1 and vice versa

Tags: java, algorithm

What is the most elegant way to do the next stuff:

```
int i = oneOrZero;

if (i == 0) {
   i = 1;
} else {
   i = 0;
}
```

You can assume that `i` can have only 1 or 0 value.

Comment: @GrayWizardx, @Carl: it's my question. I want to write integers and I do this. It's just a fragment of code after removing all dependencies unrelated to this concrete problem.

Comment: Well, I think it's a great question, and the down-votes are just sad. I'm forced to use `int` for a school assignment, so this really applies to me.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

`i ^= 1;`

[XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) the value with 1. This gives you both ways (in case you need to flip `0 <--> 1` either way):

```
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

Comment: This is not only shorter, but to me carries the meaning a little better than the subtraction answer.

Answer (score 129):

subtraction?

```
i = 1 - i;
```

Comment: nice. I thought about binary operations and didn't look to more simple solutions.

Comment: Wait... that comes from a mathematician ;)

Comment: The real question is, would you add a comment saying "flip the value of i" or just leave it alone?

Comment: @yar: I personally find XOR more meaningful in a "flip value" sense, so I'd probably comment a subtraction. However, some people get inexplicably anxious whenever they see a bitwise operator, so you might have to comment either way.

Comment: Nice. Crazy how sometimes we don't get to think simple things like this

Answer (score 8):

`i = (i == 0)?1:0` is one way, though I like @Jimmy's and @Yuval's versions better.

Comment: I prefer this one as when I read the code I know exactly what its supposed to be doing.  The subtraction is too clever for that, XOR is not common of an operation that I'm going to recognize it immediately.

Comment: @Frank Schwieterman:  In my experience, the ? operator isn't that common either.  If you've never seen the ? operator, it's not obvious what's happening.  I'd go with the XOR (and maybe comment it).

Comment: Hmm good point.  From my perspective I'm going to recognize ? before ^, but I suppose thats not universal.

Comment: @GreenMatt: I agree the both are uncommon. Rather than any personal preference or perception of overarching commonality, I'd decide based on the rest of the code base - that is, if the ternary operator is common elsewhere in code that the future developer sees, pick it; if bit-wise operations are common, go with that.  If there's no way to decide based on that criteria, performance test (which I'd guess favors XOR, but who knows).
@Chinmay: why not test on oneOrZero, and assign only once?

Comment: make it right in the declaration: int i = (oneOrZero==0)?1:0; - i suppose that assumes that there's no intervening computation that uses the value of i, which may not be accurate.

Comment: Ah, I read the OP's code as `int i = 1` OR `int i = 0` rather than a variable called oneOrZero...

Answer (score 7):

`i = ( i + 1 ) % 2`, though I think we all agree the subtraction or xor method is better!  (Though it has the added benefit of "flipping the switch" for more than binary.)

Answer (score 5):

Use Bitwise XOR operator:

```
i ^= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = 0;
x=(int)Math.cos(x);
System.out.println("X value "+x);
```