# java NOT operation in integer array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, logical-operators

I have an integer array but only with {1,0} and for some calculations I need to flip all the 1 to 0 and all the 0 to 1. right now I'm just testing them in an "if" condition. Is there a faster way to do this?

I tried with 
`t[i][j] = ~t[i][j]` 
but it doesn't work.... Also I cannot convert the array to boolean because I need to add these numbers.

Comment: there may be two solution: one is asList().forEach() + lambda, or boolean is fine: if(b) sum++;

Comment: THanks for your comment, actually I just xored :P like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411023/most-elegant-way-to-change-0-to-1-and-vice-versa