# Java code to flip 0 to 1

Tags: java

How to write a java code to flip 0 to 1 and vise versa without using loops,bit wise operators,logical operators,if-else,switch-case or ternary operators. If input is not 0 or 1 then print "error"

Comment: "without using loops,bit wise operators,logical operators,if-else,switch-case or ternary operators". So without programming....

Comment: do you mean you are looking for a build-in method or a library to do that? Because  it seems you want to write code without code

Comment: `x = 1 - x`. The `If input is not 0 or 1 then print "error"` part is hard to do without any branching though...

Comment: Okay I cannot hold back my curiosity.... **Why** would you not use all these wonderful tools?

Comment: @L.Spillner probably a homework puzzle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most elegant way to change 0 to 1 and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411023/most-elegant-way-to-change-0-to-1-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

some pseudocode, "without using loops,bit wise operators,logical operators,if-else,switch-case or ternary operators" :

```
int[] s = { 1, 0 }

try {
  x = s[x];
catch (OutofBoundsException) {
  print "error";
}
```

Comment: Good. My first idea was about using an exception.

Comment: Why not flip the array and lose the 1 - part?

Comment: This is borderline obfuscation, though.

Comment: Just because you can achieve the result like this doesn’t mean you should. Later developers will spend a couple of minutes scratching their head. Although we can assume this is a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using different exception:

```
public static void checkX (int x) {
    String message = "error";
    try {
        int y = 1/x;
        y = 1/(x-1);
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException exc) {
        x = 1 - x;
        message = Integer.toString (x);
    }
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Testing:

```
checkX(1);
checkX(0);
checkX(5);
```

Output:

```
0
1
error
```

Comment: Nice one, especially because the exception handles the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `x = 1 - x` as it has already been mentioned in comments.

It's clear to see that:

- `1 - 0` gives `1`
- `1 - 1` gives `0`

Which could be simply used as flip :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, just flip values is simple:

```
int i = 0;
i = (i + 1) % 2;
System.out.println(i); // prints 1
i = (i + 1) % 2;
System.out.println(i);  // prints 0
```

I don't know how about "error"