# variable expected when trying to change value of a variable

Tags: java

I'm a student learning java and for this code I'm writing for a homework assignment, cant use ternary operators or any if/switch statments, or add a variable and need to change the value of one of my vairables to one from 0

its a toggle method so needs to change from 0 and 1 when called

```
firstSwitchState = firstSwitchState + firstSwitchState % 2 = 0;
```

Comment: what is the condition you want to try

Comment: What do you want actually? It seems to be ambiguous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most elegant way to change 0 to 1 and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411023/most-elegant-way-to-change-0-to-1-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most elegant way to change 0 to 1 and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411023/most-elegant-way-to-change-0-to-1-and-vice-versa)

Comment: what about `1 - value` (assuming it can only be `0` and `1`)

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to toggle `firstSwitchState` from `0` to `1` or from `1` to `0`, use XOR:

```
firstSwitchState = firstSwitchState ^ 1;
```

or

```
firstSwitchState ^= 1;
```

If the original value is 1, it will become 0.

If the original value is 0, it will become 1.

Comment: its part of a toggle method so it need to change to 1 and 0 when called

Comment: @TimothyLiu in that case you need XOR (^)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Increment Operator in the following way

```
firstSwitchState = ++firstSwitchState % 2;
```