# How to change swap (change) 0 to 1 in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

Is there some nicer way how to convert 0 to 1 and vice versa in an array in JavaScript than going with for loop and converting it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411023/most-elegant-way-to-change-0-to-1-and-vice-versa), ie:

```
var variable1 = [0,1,1,0,0];
var final = []

for (var i=0; i<variable1.length; i++) {
final[i] = 1-variable1[i] 
}
//1,0,0,1,1
```

Something similar to Python's:

```py
[1-i for i in variable1]
# [1,0,0,1,1]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I'd accept all your answers which I cannot, so I at least gave you the indirect credit. I accepted the one containing all answers to make it easier for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to shorten the syntex.

```
final = variable.map(num => 1^num)
```

```js
var variable = [0,1,1,0,0];
var final1 = variable.map(num => 1-num) // way one
var final2 = variable.map(num => 1^num) // way two
console.log(final1, final2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can create a new array, I'd use `.map` instead:

```js
var variable1 = [0,1,1,0,0];

const final = variable1.map(n => 1 - n);
console.log(final);
```

Comment: I would rename `newArr` to `final` to stay consistent with the question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var variable1 = [0,1,1,0,0];

var final = variable1.map(v => v ^ 1);

console.log(final);
```

It is also looping. but I think this code is more readable.